# Each bibliography item with indent (bibtex)

Tags: bibtex, xetex

I use bibtex for my bibliography with `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}`.
My bibliography as follows:

```
 1) Toru Kitagawaand Guanyi Wang, "Who Should Get Vaccinated? Individualized
   Allocation of Vaccines Over SIR Network", 2020
```

But I need as follows:

```
    1) Toru Kitagawaand Guanyi Wang, "Who Should Get Vaccinated? Individualized
Allocation of Vaccines Over SIR Network", 2020
```

That is the line with the number should be indented (like a new paragraph) and the rest of the lines as normal text throughout the document. How can I do this? Appriciate any help

Here example of my code:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \begin{filecontents}{\biblio.bib}
 @article{key,
 author = {Toru Kitagawaand Guanyi Wang},
 year = {2020},
 title = {"Who Should Get Vaccinated? Individualized
 Allocation of Vaccines Over SIR Network"},
 }
 \end{filecontents}

 \begin{document}

 Link to biblio item \cite{key}.

 \bibliographystyle{unsrt}
 \bibliography{\biblio}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407).

Comment: Thanks, I added example of code